# Docker container requesting to itself cause a looping

Tags: docker, api, matrix, matrix-synapse

I have a container, it's running on port 8008, and it's accessible using the URL example.com. Inside the container, there's a server that provides an API and an APP. In some part of the APP, I'm making a request to the API, but when I do that, start a loop and the request never finish, and I need to restart the container.

For example, I make this request: https://example.com/server_version to get the version of the server, this request freeze the container.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Do you *actually* mean Apache Synapse here? As you've tagged [[tag:matrix]] do you actually mean [[tag:matrix-synapse]]?

Comment: I've assumed that this is an incorrect tag, if not, please do (re)tag) appropriately.